# EZGPIB: Converting Decimal String to Hexadecimal (Delphi Scripted Pascal)

Tags: hex, pascal

I want to convert a Decimal String (range between 0 and 26 Billions) to a Hexadecimal String in the Delphi-scripted Pascal-based program EZGPIB. I seem to have found a fitting piece of code on the internet, but have trouble correctly implementing it in EZGPIB. Maybe someone fluent in Pascal can help me make it work? EZGPIB is available on google and works without installation. Heres the code:

```
program hex_conv;

var
gwar:string;

function Hex(v: Longint; w: Integer): String;
var
s               : String;
i               : Integer;
hexc            : array [0 .. 15] of Char;
begin 
hexc[0] := '0';
hexc[1] := '1';
hexc[2] := '2';
hexc[3] := '3';
hexc[4] := '4';
hexc[5] := '5';
hexc[6] := '6';
hexc[7] := '7';
hexc[8] := '8';
hexc[9] := '9';
hexc[10] := 'A';
hexc[11] := 'B';
hexc[12] := 'C';
hexc[13] := 'D';
hexc[14] := 'E';
hexc[15] := 'F'; 
s[0] := Chr(w);
for i := w downto 1 do begin
s[i] := hexc[v and $F];
v := v shr 4
end;
Result := s;
end;

begin
EZGPIB_ScreenClear;
gwar:=hex(15,1);
EZGPIB_ScreenWriteLn(gwar);
gwar:=hex(1,1);
EZGPIB_ScreenWriteLn(gwar);
end.
```

The EZGPIB-compiler throws an RuntimeError if i try to compile it: Out of String Range at "s[0] := Chr(w);" If i take away the square brackets around s -> "s := Chr(w);", then the code compiles and works for a maximum input of "gwar:=hex(15,1);".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a fairly old fashioned implementation which uses knowledge about the internal workings of strings which in modern Pascal is no longer valid. s[0] referred the 'length byte' and effectively fixed the length of the string. SetLength( s, w) would be the modern equivalent.

Comment: Works like a charm! Thank you very much! :)